# Why my phone does not get alert from receiver when my app is not running on background?

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I have an app and I want to get notifications. It works fine when my phone is running background. But when I clear memory or restart my phone it is not getting notifications.

My `Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver` class. And I use this on manifest:

```
 <receiver android:name=".Main$MyReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <action android:name="com.xx.UPDATE_STATUS" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

I want to get notifications when my app is running on foreground, background , I mean every time is it possible?

Comment: It should be, that's why you use receivers.  Have you run an activity in the apk at least one time?  Until you do, the app will be in the "stopped" state and will not fire any receivers.  This is a security feature of Android.  If you force stop an app, it goes into that same stopped state.

Comment: so what I can do? think about **YO** app , how can it listen the notifications?

Comment: Assuming you have run an activity in the app at least once-  this ought to work.  Do you have the appropriate permissions requested as well?  For example you need     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

Comment: yes I have this permission : **<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />** but you siat if the app get stopped state what happens ? how can I still receive notifications?

Comment: My main class is always run when a user enter the app but if he force stop the app or clear memory what happens?

Comment: Then you won't get any receiver calls until he runs an activity in your app again.  There's no way around that, Google added it in 4.0 for security.

Comment: so for example , the same situation applies in facebook right? if I add a service and add my receiver on my service , this is the good solution for this?